# PostgreSQL. Не отображаются данные из таблицы

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Работаю с базой данных, взятой с сайта postgrepro.ru. В ходе выполнения запроса у меня не отображаются данные из колонки "model" таблицы "aircrafts" (прилагаю скрин). Не понимаю, в чём проблема. В самой таблице эти данные есть, однако они, как видите, почему-то не отображаются. У меня включена как русская, так и английская раскладка на компьютере. Локаль у меня местная стоит (ru_Ru.utf8). Пожалуйста, помогите мне. Если я где-то жёстко туплю или не понимаю простых истин, то вы уж простите меня, т.к. я в этом деле новичок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вариант, что в столбец нет данных, вы не рассматриваете?

Comment: Как я уже сказал, данные там есть

Comment: а как вы проверили, что они там есть, если они у вас не показываются?

Comment: Я просто развернул базу данных в текстовом редакторе и нашёл эту таблицу

Comment: Выше я прикрепил скрин. Как видите, в колонке model указаны модели самолётов. Однако у меня они не отображаются в ходе запроса...

Comment: `copy aircrafts_data` не имеет отношения к таблице `aircrafts`. То есть нет, из вопроса не видно, что данные в колонке действительно должны быть.

Answer (score 0):

Тип колонки у вас `TEXT`, а не `TEXT NOT NULL`,
так что предположу, что в колонке у вас просто дофига нулей.  Увидеть
это в *psql* можно, выполнив команду:

```
\pset null 'NULL'
```

После этого, нулевые значения должны отображаться строкой
`NULL`, а не пустой строкой.

Comment: В колонке не нули, а названия моделей смолётов (Boeing, Airbus и т.д.). Выше я прикрепил скрин.

Comment: @Froman  Не надо скринов, пожалуйста, здесь так не принято.  Вставляйте текст.  И ещё, вы не написали, попробовали ли вы мой вариант и какой был результат.

Comment: Хорошо, буду знать. Только я хотел бы уточнить: ваш код нужно под пользователем Postgres вводить, после подключения к базе или нет?

Comment: Это код для программы *psql.*  Без разницы, под каким юзером.  Ну и да, есть ещё вариант `SELECT model, model IS NULL FROM aircrafts LIMIT 1`.

Comment: demo=# \pset null 'NULL';
Null выводится как: "NULL;".
demo=# select * from aircrafts;
 aircraft_code | model | range 
---------------+-------+-------
 773           | NULL; | 11100
 763           | NULL; |  7900
 SU9           | NULL; |  3000
 321           | NULL; |  5600
 319           | NULL; |  6700
 733           | NULL; |  4200
 CN1           | NULL; |  1200
 CR2           | NULL; |  2700
 320           | NULL; |  5700
(9 строк)

Comment: Текст надо в вопрос, а не в комментарий к ответу!  Ну и да, в таком случае мой ответ на ваш вопрос верен.  У вас там нули.  _Почему_ у вас там нули — это уже новый вопрос.  Рекомендую задать новый вопрос, указав в нём способ импорта данных, версии софта, и вот это всё.

Comment: А вы бы не могли привести пример того, как это сделать? Указать свособ испорта данных, версию софта и т.д.

Comment: Ну, делаете новый вопрос и пишете: «Использую Ubuntu 18.04, PostgreSQL 9.6, ввожу команду pg_restore --blah-blah-blah».

Comment: Аа. Понятно. Хорошо, спасибо.